# Securing Third party libraries in web applications

Tags: javascript, security, libraries, dependency-management, owasp

I have a web application which has login page.

In the source code (specifically in the `<head>`), I can see the third party javascript libraries used and the path to this library, sometimes the version of the library.

I can even access the code of these libraries without authentication.

Is that a security risk ?

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/****/js/ui/js/jquery-ui-1.2.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/*****/dwr/interface/AjaxService.js"></script>
```

If yes, how to mitigate it?

Comment: A security risk for whom, of what attack? What is protected by the login and what do the libraries have to do with it?

Comment: on general, the concept of showing the javascripts libraries and their versions for unauthenticated users before they try to login.

Comment: Nothing about that is confidential, right? No need to protect it. Also, depending on your application, an attacker might simply create an account to gain this information.

Comment: No, it is not easy to get an account in this application.

Comment: Regardless, [your application's security should not depend on obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are two threats you need to mitigate:

- First, the authenticity of the library. This can be achieved with SRI, which is a way to check the library signature - see this [great post](https://scotthelme.co.uk/protect-site-from-cryptojacking-csp-sri/) by Scott Helme.
- Second, you want to check the library itself for know vulnerabilities. I'm not sure how it can be done when you add the libraries in that way - but there are tools you can use like [Snyk](https://snyk.io/) to test and see if the library has known security issues. For example, [here](https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:jquery@1.2.2) Snyk's results to the jquery version you're using. See [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A9-Using_Components_with_Known_Vulnerabilities) to find out more on the issue.

Hoped this help you out :)

Comment: I think you mean "known vulnerabilities", not "know dependencies".

Comment: so  , if i checked the authenticity and update to the last version, is it ok to let the libraries versions  seen by public ?

Comment: @Tom there is no way to avoid this risk completly, there are just ways to make it harder. So as long you're using this mitigations this is good enough, at least IMO. And it's really depend on the site - for example, on login page it might be better no to use any libraries at all

Comment: @Tom Notice that authenticity checks have nothing to do with the risk you are associating with showing what libraries you are using (which you still haven't explained).

Comment: @Bergi not accurate. Part of the risk is if the library contains known vulnerabilities, so this does cover it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such way has some issues.

The attacker can exploit lib server and to give you modified lib code.

First, I recommend you to download a lib (or even better is to add it to bundle via `package.json`) and to include all libs from your server, not 3rd party.

Every time you download you can check control sum of the lib to make sure it is not modified.

This will save you from some issues, but your address can be changed by the attacker too.

(He can redirect user to his host, instead of your when user resolves your address).

So it's better to have html + js in 1 file without cross link to be more safer.

This can be achieved using webpack bundling.

So attacker can compromise only the whole app, not 1 lib, it can be harder.

**EDIT**

> (However, option to have only 1 file is good only for small project. For a bigger project you should use links for perfomance and have just a bit more risk.)

And you can check the code that you have (on server or in package.json) using [snyk](https://snyk.io), which is open-source database of vulnerabilities.

**EDIT**

> One more way of protection is using [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) headers. They allow to download content of some format (styles or scripts or images or etc) using only specific list of sources. It can prevent some kinds of [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). It is highly recommended to use all types of CSP headers always. However the risk remains always: trusted source can be compromised, even DNS can be compomised.

Comment: Inline javascript (html+javascript in the same file) is absolutely not the security best practice, because it makes it impossible to have a proper content security policy (CSP) header, and XSS prevented by CSP is much more important.

Comment: @GaborLengyel You can get 1 bundle file with all csp headers set. I don't think that inlining excludes csp header using. I used webpack bundles with all csp fields set and it worked great. But that note (about csp in global) is a good solution, I'll add it to answer as an option.

Comment: You are right, my comment was written before I actually thought about it enough. It can be done, CSP will get more complex, but a good bundling solution can automate it. I should have thought twice. :) I don't necessarily agree there is an actual significant security benefit to bundling everything together during build vs downloading js from the application origin, but my previous comment was still wrong.